# Make an Behaviorsubject for nested serializer's data

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, behaviorsubject, rxjs-observables

I try to make an articles app.
[image: 1]

based on angular and ionic but the problem I face is the programming structure for **Behaviorsubject** for the serializer nested data.
My backend uses django-rest-framework

*I successfully perform "CRUD" operations **(I.e. live updates from server and behavior subject)** with basic data I.e. only with author data or article data **but failed with nested serialize data** *

All I want the best practice of behavior subject for the nested data of authors and articles

Question.) Make an Behaviorsubject for one URLs
*http:local host:8000/v1/authors/* 
Which Uses **nested serializer** and returns both **authors and articles data**
*Below image* ?

Below image shows authors array  data *with* **articles data** of second model as nested 
(Thanks in advance)

[1]:

Code of my **articles.service.ts**

```
  extractArticles(data : AuthorsInterface[]){
/*
* Extracting then Returns
  * [] of Articles Data
  * from Parent Data
*/

let localArray = []
if (data.length > 0){
  for( let x in data ){
    if ( data[x].articles.length > 0 ){
      for( let y in data[x].articles){
        localArray.push(data[x].articles[y])
      }
    }
  }
  return this.articlesInterface.concat(localArray)
}
```

}

```
getParents() {
/*
* Calling REST-API
  * Extract Authors & Articles
  * from the parent Data
  * & cached them
*/
return this.http.get<AuthorsInterface[]>(this.AUTHOR_URL)
  .pipe(
    map(mapData=>{
        **here comes the combined data of articles and authors **
        *as shown in image*
        this.articlesBehavior.next(
        this.extractArticles(mapData)
      )        
    }
  )
)
```

**Am i doing right ?**

*Right now i just split the data after recieving from backend
 (by extracting the article's data from author's dictionary)
and store it separetely

*articlesInterface for holding all the article
*authorsInterface for holding all the authors*

**Then inject article's service into authors's service don't know it's a best practice or not ?**

I made two BehaviorSubject

Comment: You want to use BehaviourSubject to pass data?

Comment: Provide the code for 'CRUD' operations which you have done

Comment: Brother i update the post with my "code" as you asking,glad if you help me :)

Comment: Do you want to post nested data to backend or read nested data? I am having difficulty understanding your question.

Comment: I am comfortable with the "CRUD" operations by making one BehaviorSubject  but this time how can i handle the **nested data** coming from server having two models articles and authors as shown in pictures. **Question** - *How can i make the **structure** of **service.ts** and **Behavior Subject** (*should i make two service file or two BehaviorSubject one for articles and one for authors* ) as per data coming from backend. Goal here not to send request to the server for data which can be cached. **How to handle or cached nested data properly in order to re-use it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `Article` inside the `Author` model:

```
export interface Article {
  // fields for articles
}

export interface Author {
  // fields for autor
  articles: Article[]
}
```

This will ensure that the data you are getting from `authors` endpoint will match with the `Author` model and for `articles` endpoint use `Article` model.

There is no need to split the data coming from `authors` endpoint.

If there is a requirement to list all articles irrespective of author, then create a new url which returns all the articles and use `Article` model for that.

Comment: Am i thinking wrong ?  That if entire articles data already coming from authors data, so why we calls **api** for article section , just use behaviorsubject to store it and call it everytime we need------------------------------------------------------------------------ I successfully retrieve the author's data

Comment: If the articles data belongs to a author, there is no need to separate it.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply , Any blog or example which shows nested data calling with proper Observable for caching it ?

Comment: Actually i reliaze,i have to calls two api one for **articles/** and second for **authors/** But i think calls all the data once using **realated nested serialzer** _and store it_ for later use and no need to calls aritlces data . ** I think that was an mistake **